# Regex strip out returns whitespace from inside brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex expression that will remove all line breaks/returns/whitespace/tabs from inside only the first bracket match.

For example:

```
foo\r

{{\n    $uppercase($for(Baz, "roar\\n foo {{value}} \\r"))\n    }}
{{$uppercase("baz\n") }}

baz
```

would ideally return:

```
foo\r

{{$uppercase($for(Baz, "roar\\n foo {{value}} \\r"))}}
{{$uppercase("baz\n")}}

baz
```

I tried something like this:

```
/(?:\{\{)(?:(?:\n)|(?:\r\n))(?:\\r)\t(?:\}\})/g
```

but doesn't seem to get the matching correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to parse arbitrary source code using regex. Regex is basically not capable of doing this. I recommend using a parser like Antlr. You may also have an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so more context about what you're doing and confirmation that this antipattern is the best/necessary approach to solve whatever problem you need to solve seems important to include. It _looks like_ you're parsing jinja/ejs-like templated strings in source code files. Is this a one-off use case or ...? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ggorlen - I had a feeling that would be the answer but wanted to double check. The code is for fixing expressions in a mustache-like template that a user might have corrupted. My hope was to have a simple-ish regex to strip that out. What about if we said forget only looking for first and said anything inside not in quotes?

Comment: So you're asking how to do a replacement on substrings inside of `{{ }}`s only but not inside quotes? Probably multiple passes are necessary--once to grab all of the `{{ }}` areas (not exactly "easy" since `{{ }}` could themselves be in quoted areas), then something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351377/regexp-find-all-occurences-but-not-inside-quotes) to find/replace all occurrences of each character not inside quotes. It may be doable, but I recommend clearly defining the specification using a variety of input/output examples with a short rationale for each desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick! The idea being split the string into your chunks based on matching brackets, those with the brackets and those without. Loop through your chunks, find chunks that have dual brackets, then remove all line breaks from just that chunk. Once complete with the loop, reassemble as a string. Voilà.

```
const newString = str.split(/({{.*?}})/sg).reduce((a, v) => 
  (v.includes('{{') ? a + v.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"") : a+v)
,'');
```